# How do you print the Django SQL query for an aggregation?

Tags: python, django, orm

If I have a django queryset `print(queryset.query)` shows me the SQL statement so I can validate it.  But with aggregations they never return a queryset.  How do you print those queries out.

I guess I can turn on debug logging for the ORM and find them that way but it seems like I should be able to get it right before the execution engine sends it off to postgres.....

Comment: Isn't that what happens if you turn debug logging on? And isn't that opposite of what you do with `queryset.query`?

Comment: I was hoping for a way to print it while debugging without having to do all the logging setup, while I'm in the middle of the code vs setting everything up and coming back to that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `connection.queries` after your aggregation query.

Example:

```py
...
from django.db import connection

def your_view(request):
    # Your view logic and aggregate queryset
    
    print(connection.queries)  

    return render(request, 'index.html', {})
```

The **output is a dictionary of SQL queries** that you entered into the database.

Comment: Yea, using DjDT would give me access to it.  Not a bad idea.